# How to make HTML tables header fixed using CSS, all other rows should be scrollable? It should work on IE8+, Latest Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        .container {
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 300px;
        }
        table {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        td + td {
            border-left: 1px solid #eee;
        }
        td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            background: #ddd;
            color: #000;
            padding: 10px 25px;
        }
        thead tr {
            background-color: #12abcd;
        }
        th {
            height: 20px;
            color: black;
            border: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        </style>
        <title>Table</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="header">
                            <th>
                                Table attribute name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Value
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Description
                            </th>
    
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Blue</td>
                            <td>left, center, right</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gray</td>
                            <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Pink</td>
                            <td>1,""</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gel</td>
                            <td>pixels</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, secell content</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Joe</td>
                            <td>pixels</td>
                            <td>NLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ses</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se should be visible</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Drew</td>
                            <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
                            <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bist</td>
                            <td>text</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Frog</td>
                            <td>pixels, %</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Truth</td>
                            <td>pixels, %</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Dare</td>
                            <td>pixels, %</td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Positioning it fixed doesn't seem to work, is there any other alternative for this?

Something like this for example http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html. It should work in IE8+, Latest Chrome and Firefox

Comment: If you look at the code in the page you linked to, you will notice that there are applied CSS styles, like: ``display: block;``, ``width``, ``height`` and ``overflow`` to the ``<tbody/>`` element. That makes the effect working ;)

Comment: It should run in IE8 and above as well. This solution doesnt

Comment: Like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/7UZA4/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559197/how-to-make-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers-using-css

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in IE8.

Comment: Don't think you can with pure css

Answer (score 2):

**working fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

```
section {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding-top: 37px;
      background: #500;
    }
    section.positioned {
      position: absolute;
      top:100px;
      left:100px;
      width:800px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
    }
    .container {
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 200px;
    }
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      width:100%;
    }
    td + td {
      border-left:1px solid #eee;
    }
    td, th {
      border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
      background: #ddd;
      color: #000;
      padding: 10px 25px;
    }
    th {
      height: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      color: transparent;
      border: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    th div{
      position: absolute;
      background: transparent;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 9px 25px;
      top: 0;
      margin-left: -25px;
      line-height: normal;
      border-left: 1px solid #800;
    }
    th:first-child div{
      border: none;
    }



<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```